# How to typeset 'et al.' in italic with the agsm bibliography style?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib, italic

I'm using the `natbib` package with the `agsm` bibliographic style to generate and use the bibliography in a report.

But whenever I cite an article having many authors, the layout in the document is 'Author et al.'

Which command can I use to have the following result: 'Author. F *et al.*', i.e. to italicize 'et al.'?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this from within your source file, since the `et~al.` string is hard-coded into the `agsm.bst` file itself.  But it's not too hard to make a modified copy of the `.bst` file to do what you want.

First locate the original `agsm.bst` file.  You can find the exact path for your system by using `kpsewhich agsm.bst` from the command line. On a current TeXLive system it is in:

```
 /usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/harvard/agsm.bst
```

Make a copy of this file, and call it e.g. `agsm-italic-etal.bst`.  Put this in your local `texmf` folder: `...texmf/bibtex/bst/` or simply place it in the same folder as your source document if you only need this style for that document.

Now in the copied `.bst` file, search for `et~al.` and replace it with `\emph{et~al.}`.  There should be five occurrences of it.  Save your changes and in your source document use

```
\bibliographystyle{agsm-italic-etal}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I did so with an agsm.bst file that i've downloaded, and it works.