# How to Typeset "et al" in italics

Tags: citing, natbib

I'm using `natbib`, `setcitestyle` packages and `agsm` style. I want to italicize words "et al" so that they appear as "*et al*".

I have located and changed the `agsm.bst` file (5 instances of `et~al` to `**\emph{et~al}**`) and placed it in the same folder as my work. I have also pointed the biography style to new bst file. However, I see no change in citations.

I'm using TexStudio and Windows 8. I have gone through previous posts concerning this issue without success.

Previous posts on this issue:

[Using natbib and plainnat - no year appears to some references and also et al. not in Italics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15730/using-natbib-and-plainnat-no-year-appears-to-some-references-and-also-et-al-n)

[How to typeset 'et al.' in italic with the agsm bibliography style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/382742/how-to-typeset-et-al-in-italic-with-the-agsm-bibliography-style)

..and many others.

Please help.

MWE:

MinimumWorkingExample.tex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{Thesis}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{aysep={,}} 
\begin{document}
    Here is a minimum working example:

    Single author~\cite{yeung2007reducing}. In the second line, we provide an example of citing more than 3 authors so as to test of the words et al are italicized~\cite{samadi2010optimal}.
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{MWERef}
\end{document}
```

MWERef.bib File:

```
    @inproceedings{samadi2010optimal,
  title={Optimal real-time pricing algorithm based on utility maximization for smart grid},
  author={Samadi, Pedram and Mohsenian-Rad, Amir-Hamed and Schober, Robert and Wong, Vincent WS and Jatskevich, Juri},
  booktitle={Smart Grid Communications (SmartGridComm), 2010 First IEEE International Conference on},
  pages={415--420},
  year={2010},
  organization={IEEE}
}
@article{yeung2007reducing,
  title={Reducing energy costs with peak shaving in industrial environments},
  author={Yeung, Phillip},
  journal={Schneider Electric, September},
  year={2007}
}
```

Output:

[image]

Thanks for your comments guys. MWE works, but my thesis document still cannot italicize the words et al. I will have to look for conflicting packages in the thesis document because MWE contains fewer packages than the thesis document.

Comment: It must be `\emph{et~al}` not `emph(et~al)` (`\ ` added and `{…}` instead of `(…)`). Have you run `bibtex` again? And do you mean `\setcitestyle` command? Can you please show us a minimal working example with bibliography and documentation of your changes? Currently we cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Schweinebacke, what you have suggested is what I have done in the modified .bst file. I just made a mistake when posting here. Regarding \setcitestyle command, I have used it to separate author and year by a comma. Without the command, i get "(Schweinebacke 2017)", instead of "(Schweinebacke,2017)"

Comment: @Mico, It is really a duplicate question, however solutions suggested in related various posts do not work for my case. I was wondering if you can help me identify what am doing wrongly.

Comment: Please add/correct the information in the question! Questions should always be self-explaining without the need to read any comment!

Comment: @DanielJ. Can you please add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)?

Comment: @DanielJ. - Have you performed a full recompile cycle (LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX twice more), to fully propagate the changes you made to the bibliography style file?

Comment: Your MWE loads the `agsm` bibliography style, which is known *not* to italicize the string "et al". Have you tried the adjustments recommended in the linked answers?

Comment: The posted MWE works, however my thesis document doesn't. Since MWE works, I believe I can be able to fix my thesis document. I guess I have conflicting packages in the thesis document that prevent agsm from working. This means I correctly changed the agsm.bst file.